# start the wolfram framework in X11 mode

Tags: xorg

I connect to my raspi by ssh with X11 forwarding enabled. I can start xclock and it gets displayed to my X Display on a Fedora system, so no problem there.

I then installed the wolfram package and try to start it in X11 mode, but it always only starts the interactive shell. What do I need to do to start the wolfram package in X11 mode to display it on my remote computer?

Comment: Running `mathematica` via SSH brought up the Wolfram Mathematica window remotely for me.

Comment: thanks, that was it, I just started the wrong program. Sorry I am new to this software :) please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the right answer.

Comment: Just curious, what program were you running?

Comment: I used the "wolfram" command, but this is just the interpreter for the language. And when I took a look into the package with dpkg -L I just must have missed the mathematica command.

Comment: Please excuse me for this related question. I also use mathematica in a RPi in a exported X11 display over SSH in a LAN, and it is rather slow. Even typing is slow, if you type quickly, the interface has to catch you. I was wondering if this also happens in the local X server or if it only happens in remote. I don't have my RPi connected to a display. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the problem was to run the command `mathematica` from the command prompt.